# combining 3 separate arrays to one multidimensional array in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, array

Is possible to create multidimensional arrays in bash scripting?

These are my 3 arrays:

```
arrayCITY=( NewYork LasVegas Detroit )
arraySTREET=( RoadStreet TreeStreet HighStreet )
arrayNUMBER=( 20 455 300 )
```

Now I want to put these 3 arrays in just one array -- is this possible? Then I want to show them in a txt file. Now I do it like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#arrayCITY[*]}; i++));do
  echo "${arrayCITY[i]} ${arraySTREET[i]} ${arrayNUMBER[i]}" >> TEXT.txt
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man 1 bash`:

```
Arrays
       Bash  provides one-dimensional indexed and associative array variables.  Any variable
       may be used as an indexed array; the  declare  builtin  will  explicitly  declare  an
       array.   There  is no maximum limit on the size of an array, nor any requirement that
       members be indexed or assigned contiguously.  Indexed  arrays  are  referenced  using
       integers  (including  arithmetic  expressions) and are zero-based; associative arrays
       are referenced using  arbitrary  strings.   Unless  otherwise  noted,  indexed  array
       indices must be non-negative integers.
```

Key phrase:

> Bash  provides one-dimensional indexed and associative array variables.

So, no, bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this just now.  There is a fairly simple solution that worked for me.  I wanted to use an array that contained a device name and a screen position to display a key map for the device.  I did the following:
I concatenated the device name and the associated screen position
into a single string, using a delimiter (in my case, I used **`.`**)
that I knew would not appear in any of my values. 
Then I used `cut` to break the composite values apart into their components
when needed.  There might be a cleaner and simpler way to do this, but this is just to show that you can create a multidimensional array, in a way, in bash, even though it doesn't support it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# List of devices and screen positions for key maps.
DEV_LIST=( g13.+2560+30 g510s.+3160+30 g502.+2560+555 )

# This just echoes the device name and the screen position.
for DEV in "${DEV_LIST[@]}"; do
    DEVICE=$(echo $DEV | cut -f1 -d.)
    SCREEN_POSITION=$(echo $DEV | cut -f2 -d.)
    echo "$DEVICE"
    echo "$SCREEN_POSITION"
done

exit
```

This is somewhat similar to [Coop.Computer’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323790/23408#403691).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works for me.
If we first set up the array like this:

```bsh
    arrayCSR=( Placeholder_for_0_spot NewYork RoadStreet 20 LasVegas TreeStreet 455 Detroit HighStreet 300 )
```

The placeholder is there to avoid having to deal with a 0 index.

Then, each "row" is anything that can be divided by 3, and each "column" is 1 or 2 less than the "row" number.

```
${arrayCSR[${3}]} is 20
${arrayCSR[${2}]} is RoadStreet
${arrayCSR[${1}]} is NewYork
```

A sample script is below:

```bsh
    arrayCSR=( CsR NewYork RoadStreet 20 LasVegas TreeStreet 455 Detroit HighStreet 300 )

    for p in $( seq 1 ${#arrayCSR[*]} )
    do
        if [[ "${arrayCSR[${p}]}" == "" ]] # Don't run if empty
        then
            true
        elif [[ $((p % 3 )) -eq 0 ]] # We have 3 "columns" in the array
        then
            echo " ${arrayCSR[$(( p - 2 ))]} ${arrayCSR[$(( p - 1))]} ${arrayCSR[${p}]}"
        fi
    done
```

So any index that can divide by 3 indicates a "row", and also the third "column" in the row. To get the second and first "column", subtract 1 or 2 accordingly.

This can also scale up if needed.

Update:
Below is code that I use to load and array of string replacements for file names. The first array is loaded from a file, then is split into 2 separate arrays.

```bsh
        readarray -t string_replace < ~/scripts/string_replace.lst # List of things to remove from name
    
        for p in $( seq 0 ${#string_replace[*]} ); do
            old_name_element[${p}]="${string_replace[${p}]%%,*}"
            new_name_element[${p}]="${string_replace[${p}]:$((${#old_name_element[${p}]}+1))}"
        done
        string_replace=() # Clear old array
```

Comment: That's a neat way to fake a 2D array if the length of all elements are known (and consistent), but will of course not work for variable length elements.

Comment: For me, the simple way would be to just use 3 arrays, with the index being the common link between them.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I like Bash, it makes sense to sometimes switch to other languages. This is fairly straightforward using a dictionary in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

cities = { 
            "New York": { "Street": "Roadstreet", "Number": 20 },
            "Las Vegas": { "Street": "TreeStreet", "Number": 455 }    
         }

for city in cities:
    print(str(city) + ": " + str(cities[city]["Street"])
    + " " + str(cities[city]["Number"]))
```

Running this yields:

```
./cities.py 
New York: Roadstreet 20
Las Vegas: TreeStreet 455
```